# Flutter Google map Navigation back is crashing with IOS

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am encountering an issue with the Google Maps Widget navigation feature on iOS. Whenever I try to go back, the app crashes abruptly.

This problem is specific to iOS, as I have tested it on Android where the app does not crash but the navigation is not smooth.

This is the code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const AppBarWidget(),
      body: GoogleMap(
        markers: _markers,
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: LatLng(widget.lat, widget.long), zoom: 13),
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: ButtonWidget(
        title: 'Go to Google Map',
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () async {
        
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the only logs

```
[        ] Lost connection to device.
```

Is there a known solution or workaround for this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My expectation that to navigate back well without crashing and to be smooth

Comment: Are you using `google_maps_flutter`? If so, have you tried filing an issue in the github repo itself? I can see a few iOS issues in the library itself that might be related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22p%3A+maps%22